# All product not display in Add Product Manaully Section of Configurable products

Tags: magento2

In my Magento i have these Product List:-

[image]
But when i go to Customizable Product and Select the option 
**Add Product Manaully**
Can't find all Product list..
Like This in My Image

[image]

Why my All Store Product List Not Display in this section ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `Add Product Manually Section` of Configurable products does not show complete products because it only show the `simple product` which are become the associated products of `configurable product`.

In your above image, there are other types of products as well like `Virtual`, `Downloadable`, `Grouped` and `Configurable` product. So that why it these products do not display in `Add Product Manually Section` of configurable product. It is basic magento concept

**I hope this will help**